# CMS Strapi - response with partial model data

Tags: reactjs, strapi

I have a web page on which I want to present a set of client's articles. A single article is comprised of - *Title*, *Author*, *Short description*, *Article's body*. On the main page I would like to display all available articles in the shorter form, including only *Title* and *Short description*.

When I create on Strapi's backend collection of Articles (with aforementioned fields) getting all articles (via GET request) involves fetching all article's data (*Title*, *Author*, *Short description* and *Article's body*), whereas at the main page the only information required are *Title* and *Short description*.

Is there a way to design it on Strapi's backend so that only a partial information be sent in a response?

Comment: Pretty sure Strapi comes with a graphql API, if youre willing to go that route. That allows you to set what properties should be included. Regular REST APIs arent usually as dynamic.

Comment: @zero298 Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @zero298 suggested, **graphql** is the best way to achieve what you want.

The **other way** to do that is by `customizing your api's repsonse.`

When you create a content type, it generates an API with the following list of [endpoints](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/content-api/api-endpoints.html#endpoints).

Each of these endpoint triggers a controller action. Here is the list of [controller actions](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/concepts/controllers.html)that exist by default when a content type is created.

If you check the controller file of your generated API `./api/{content-type}/controller/{Content-Type}.js`, you will see an empty file. It is because all the default logic is managed by Strapi. But you can override these actions with your own code.

Refer to the following documentation [Example](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/guides/custom-data-response.html#example). This example explains exactly the use case that you want.

***But,i prefer using the graphQL enpoint provided by Strapi***. This is much simpler to use especially for your use case.

**Steps**:

- Login as the super admin user , and select plugins and then install the graphql plugin.
  You can also install the plugin through terminal using npm or yarn ( eg. `npm run strapi install graphql`)
- Then, start your app and open your browser at http://localhost:1337/graphql (opens new window). You should see the interface (GraphQL Playground) that will help you to write GraphQL query to explore your data.
- To perform authorized requests, you must first get a JWT. Refer to the [link](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/plugins/graphql.html#authentication) on how to perform the authorized requests.
- To perform query request you can resfer to [Query api](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/plugins/graphql.html#query-api) .For each model, the plugin auto-generates queries and mutations which just fit to your needs

This is how you can start using the graphQL. Btw, from you application, you would be needing a graphql client to perform the requests.  You can refer to this article for the popular list of [graphql clients](https://blog.bitsrc.io/6-top-graphql-clients-for-2020-259e8034ba42). For simple use cases, I prefer [graphql-request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-request).

For response with partial use case data your  `graphql-request` query could be something like:

```
import { GraphQLClient, gql } from 'graphql-request'

async function main() {
  const endpoint = 'your graphql endpoint'

  const graphQLClient = new GraphQLClient(endpoint, {
    headers: {
      authorization: 'Bearer MY_TOKEN',
    },
  })

  const query = gql`
    {
      Article {
        Title
        Short description
      }
    }
  `
  const data = await graphQLClient.request(query)
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2))
}

main().catch((error) => console.error(error));
```

One of the **drawbacks** using the `graphql` instead of the `REST` endpoints is that, you need to specify all the fields that you require in the response. So, if you need all the fields for an endpoint you need to explicitly specify all the field names in the query.

Comment: What about caching mechanism? Is it possible to have fetched strapi's data somehow cached locally so that the next time it wouldn't be necessary to have it requested again (unless of course some data on the backend would've been changed)?

Comment: For caching needs, Apollo, Relay and FlacheQL are the libraries for client-side caching. But FlacheQl has advantage in the sense that it offers partial retrieval of cached data based on search parameters — a feature that no other GraphQL library offers. Larger implementations like Apollo and Relay can only cache data based on GraphQL query fields. Refer [this](https://medium.com/@sasilver0051/graphql-client-side-caching-in-2019-76e97bffecfc) article

Comment: That's very useful thanks for that info. The last one I've got is it possible (and if so, how it is achievable) for every single article to have a different end point? So that if a client's site is site.com each and every single article would've have it's own url such as site.com/my-awesome-article etc? Thanks

Comment: Not sure but I dont think that's possible!!

Comment: If you're not sure then it's probably possible :) Thanks anyway